# Can reverse proxy rules affect apache reverse proxy performance?

Tags: performance, apache, reverse-proxy

Just a few questions about reverse proxies and performance.

Will there be an effect on performance if i have too many rules in my reverse proxy?

For example, If I have 200 rules which are similiar to the following:

```
ProxyPass        /website/test/            http://www.example:8080/web/test
ProxyPassReverse /website/test/            http://www.example:8080/web/test
```

Will there be a performance improvement if i have 100, what happens if i have 1000?

Will my reverse proxy perform better if i use a rewrite rule?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get accurate numbers one would have to benchmark this, and preferably with your architecture, software versions, and server. However think of it like this:

- One ProxyPass rule causes one string comparison, probaby by using PCRE.
- All ProxyPassReverse rules cause string comparison (and potentially search & replace) against 5 header fields.
- Your production server can probably handle some 5+ million ProxyPass and 1+ million ProxyPassReverse operations per second.

However notice that you probably don't need as many stanzas. You can combine them by doing things like

```
ProxyPass        /website/test/            http://www.example:8080/web/test
ProxyPass        /website/test2/           http://www.example:8080/web/test2
ProxyPassReverse /website/                 http://www.example:8080/web
```

The performance hit of having hundreds of ProxyPass and ProxyPassReverse stanzas probably will not bother you much, although it is never wrong to optimize your configuration.

Comment: Great answer. Do you have a source for 5+ million ProxyPass and 1+ million ProxyPassReverse ops?

Comment: @ChrisBetti I’ve the same question, did you find the answer?